# Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import_modules/@angular/core/core")'. how to resolve this angular error in html files

Tags: node.js, angular, error-handling, web-development-server, angular-fullstack

automatically show this error in my all angular html page how to resolve this anyone suggest plz.
i am use node version 14.17.4 and my angular version is 15.
Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import_modules/@angular/core/core")'. how to resolve this angular error in html files. complie time error and not resolve and show automatically so suggest any one.

Comment: Angular 15 does not contain signals. What are your project dependencies in package.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issue with the error message "Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import," follow these steps:

Solution:
Step 1: Stop the running Angular server and close the editor.
Step 2: Now Open your project again and, before opening any file in the editor, start your Angular server using the command ng serve.
Step 3: (Optional) remove the cookies from your browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might arise from opening the code editor in a parent folder of the angular project.
i.e. if opening a top folder for the project and then cd into the angular folder and in parelal cd into the server-side folder.
[Don't do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlA8f.jpg)
To resolve this issue simply open 2 instances of the code editor, and in each directly open the desired folder
[Do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waatz.jpg)