# Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import("e:/project/myApp/myApp/node_modules/@angular/core/core") [(ngModel)] Error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive

Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import("e:/project/eCeiling/e-ceiling/node_modules/@angular/core/core")
[(ngModel)] showing me error
i have imported formsmodule ,common module it not workig my angular version is 13.3.9

[(ngModel)] two way binding not working for me it should be work

<input type="number"  name="size" matInput style="font-weight:   sbold;" [(ngModel)]="gridsize"
placeholder="Records in percent(%)" min="0" max="100"
(input)="updateSetting(gridsize)" required>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import\_modules/@angular/core/core")'. how to resolve this angular error in html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77992372/property-%c9%b5unwrapwritablesignal-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-import-modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import,"

I restart my editor and serve my application  after closing
the error not showing.